# how to get C++0x / C++11 style range-based for loops to work with clang?

Tags: c++, for-loop, clang, c++11

I've been taking advantage of range-based for loops in C++0x/11 using gcc w/ -std=c++0x like so:

```
for (int i : container) ...
```

I recently tried clang (clang+llvm-2.9-x86_64-apple-darwin10), but out-of-the-box these statements were compilation errors. According to http://clang.llvm.org/cxx_status.html it's supported. I tried adding -stdlib=libc++ on the command-line, but then I get an error that the iostream header isn't found. What do I need to do to get clang to work with C++0x/11 functionality?

Comment: What is the code that you are trying to compile?  Have you tried including `<iostream>`?  Does clang know where to find the Standard Library?  If you remove the range-based for loop, does the code compile?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The secret here is that LLVM 2.9 doesn't support range-based for loops.  That document corresponds to LLVM/Clang mainline.  To get range-based for loops, please check out LLVM/Clang from mainline SVN: http://clang.llvm.org/get_started.html

libc++ is useful for C++'0x ('11!) library support, but you also have to set it up if you want to use its functionality on top of C++'0x language features.  For information on how to set it up, please see: http://libcxx.llvm.org/